# Why do I need ./ to run an application?

Tags: command-line

I wrote a little [Hello world program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program). When I tried to run `a.out`, I got "command not found".  When I ran `./a.out`, it worked fine.

Where can I learn about why that was?